# Hibernate: Persisting Objects

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to create new Event objects to be persisted in the database via Hibernate. The below code successfully creates one event, but when session.save(evt) is called, I get a return value of 0 (which I think is the equivalent of null). Can anyone identify what the issue is below? If you need more information in regards to classes or hibernate mapping files involved, please request what you need.

Note: Assume an events table exists in the database.

```
public class ScheduleUnitOfWork {
private Map<Service, Employee> assignments;
private Date startDate;
private Date endDate;
private String customerName;

public ScheduleUnitOfWork(Map<Service, Employee> assignments, Date startDate,
                          Date endDate, String customerName) {
    super();

    this.assignments = assignments;
    this.startDate = startDate;
    this.endDate = endDate;
    this.customerName = customerName;
}

public boolean scheduleEmployees(){
    Session session = SessionFactoryUtil.getInstance().getCurrentSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    boolean retVal = true;

    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();

        for(Service s : assignments.keySet()){
            Employee e = assignments.get(s);

            Event evt = new Event();
            evt.setAssignedService(s);
            evt.setCustomerName(this.customerName);
            evt.setEndDate(endDate);
            evt.setStartDate(startDate);

            System.out.println(session.save(evt));
        }

        tx.commit();

    }catch(RuntimeException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();

        if(tx != null){
            tx.rollback();
        }
        session.close();

        retVal = false;
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

}

```
<class name="Event" table="Events">
    <id name="ID" column="ID" type="int">
        <generator class="assigned"/>
    </id>
    <property name="startDate" column="startDate" type="timestamp"/>
    <property name="endDate" column="endDate" type="timestamp"/>
    <property name="customerName" column="customerName" type="string"/>
    <many-to-one name="assignedService" column="serviceID" 
                class="org.hibernate.service.Service"
                unique="true" not-null="true"/>

</class>
```

Comment: Seeing a mapping for Event would help (.hbm.xml or annotated class). Have you specified a generator for its id?

Comment: I added the class definition in the hibernate file to the question above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your generator class is "assigned" meaning Hibernate will take the ID "as is" - e.g. it will assume **you** are setting it.

Take a look at [various generator classes](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id) supported by Hibernate. If you want your ID to be auto-generated, most common approaches are "identity" (if your database supports it) or "sequence".

Comment: I changed the generator class to be identitiy and I see save returning a non-zero value that is incrementing. However, I still do not see the database table getting updated. I tried flushing the session buffer, but that did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: If you're getting back an id from "identity" that means the row **was** inserted but transaction was subsequently rolled back. Are you getting any errors back when you're committing the transaction by any chance?

Comment: Found the error: In the MySQL query browser I was using, I kinda forgot to refresh my view of the browser. Events are now getting added, thank you!